# Upload CSV to MongoDB using Yeoman Angular-Fullstack

Tags: mongodb, angular-fullstack

I have tried many file upload modules for Angular, Node, Express, but just don't know how to wire it together. Would someone please start from the beginning to walk me through an example?
Thank you.